# How to use fork in C

Tags: c, fork

I wrote a short program that multiplies and divides two values in the two processes.
The problem occurs at the end of the application, when added together I want the results of multiplication and division.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    int iloczyn, a, b;
    int *w_iloczyn, *w_a, *w_b;

    float iloraz, suma, result;
    float *w_iloraz, *w_suma, *w_result;

    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);

    w_a = &a;
    w_b = &b;

    pid_t id = fork();

    if (id == 0) {

        iloczyn = (*w_a) * (*w_b);

        w_iloczyn = &iloczyn;

        printf("%d * %d = %d\n", *w_a, *w_b, *w_iloczyn);

    } else {

        int status = 255;

        id = wait(&status);

        id = waitpid(id, &status, 0);

        iloraz = (float) *w_a / (float) *w_b;
        w_iloraz = &iloraz;

        printf("%d / %d = %f\n", *w_a, *w_b, *w_iloraz);
     }

    printf("Iloczyn: %i\n", *w_iloczyn);

    printf("Iloraz: %f\n\n", *w_iloraz);

    return 1;
}
```

The result of addition is a violation of memory protection.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Processes don't share memory.

Comment: The parent and child processes have separate address spaces.

Comment: if you want to share memory you need a thread instead of a new process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `fork()` the result is two separate processes. They do not share any memory (technically they do but changes don't propagate) so any pointers you use are not valid in the child process necessarily.

So there are several problems: the pointers to local variables may point to completely wrong places, their values might not match and no values are returned to the parent process by changing the values of local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Fork crate new processes. From that moment, both processes (the original and the new one) change different memory block by accessing the variables. That means, that in the first process to the variable w_iloraz is never assigned any value and in the second process there is nothing assigned to the variable w_iloczyn.

If you want to share data between processes, have a look at IPC (Inter-process communication).
You can use shared memory (using functions shmget,shmat, shmdt etc.). You need to use functions like sem_open, sem_wait, sem_post and sem_close to work with shared memory.

You can also use (unnamed) pipes (see man pipe), or named pipes (see mkfifo).